# JavaScript switch statement is not executing case 1

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get case 1 of my code to execute but for some reason that is not happening I am fairly new to JS and I used w3 school to use switch statement but for some reason it will not execute case 1 I even removed the breaks

```js
let theGreeting = String(prompt("enter your name"));
console.log("hello " + theGreeting + " " + "how are you I hope well");
let theQuestion = Boolean(prompt("enter boolean value "));

switch (theQuestion) {
  case 0:
    theQuestion == false;
    console.log("it was" + theQuestion + "that is very good to hear that you were not sick ");
    break;

  case 1:
    theQuestion == true;
    console.log("sorry to hear that it is " + theQuestion + " " + "that you were very sick ");
    break;

};

let theNumber = Number(prompt("enter number"));
console.log("I am sorry to hear that I am surprised that the treatment was" +
    " " + theNumber * theNumber + " " + " dollars " + "thank god for insurance ");
```

Comment: `theQuestion == true;` is not assignment, it's an equality check. change all instances to `theQuestion = true` / `theQuestion = false`

Comment: that did not help I changed the swtich cases to have = not == but still has the same issue

Comment: Check my edited answer  @J1N1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't execute it because your not returning nothing to a variable.

Also using boolean is not very correct, as if someone writes anything else than true of false it wouldn't work.

Check that with a while loop instead.
Also if you're just using that code, try using var instead of let.

And your making your case 0 or 1, which doesn't make sense, as you want true or false.

Try this instead:

```
let theGreeting = String(prompt("enter your name"));
console.log("hello " + theGreeting + " " + "how are you I hope well");
let theQuestion = Boolean(prompt("enter boolean value "));

switch (theQuestion) {
case true:
theQuestion = false;
console.log("it was" + theQuestion + "that is very good to hear that you were 
not sick");
 break;

  case false:
 theQuestion = true;
 console.log("sorry to hear that it is " + theQuestion + " " + "that you were 
 very sick");
 break;

};

 let theNumber = Number(prompt("enter number"));
  console.log("I am sorry to hear that I am surprised that the treatment was" 
+ " " + theNumber * theNumber + " " + " dollars " + "thank god for 
insurance");
```

And an **Extra bonus tip**, indent your code, with spaces or tabs, but please indent it, not only for our sake, but for yours too.

Good Luck!!

Comment: lol you have no idea I been told that many times I am working on it, thanks alot for the help